# Autoconf, Libtool, and an undefined AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

Tags: autoconf

I am trying to build a library, and the README instructions are to call configure.ac, then make.

Unfortunately, I am running into an error:

```
configure.ac:75 :error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
    If this token is legitimate please use m4_pattern_allow
```

Now, I know I have libtool installed  (I'm running Scientific Linux 6.2 (un-upgraded), and have used yum --downloadonly to get the rpms of automake, autoconf, libtool, and libtool-devel just in case).

They are installed, and libtool currently lives in /usr/share/libtool. However, autoconf can't seem to find it.

All of the google results were of the 'install libtool' kind, which doesn't help me at all. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated. I'm not sure if the issue is that rpm -i screwed up getting libtool on here, or if i need to link the /usr/share/libtool to somewhere else (so which and everything else can find it).

Answer (score 17):

I wasn't satisfied with all the "just reinstall" answers I've found all over the Internet in various forums, so was bound and determined to resolve this without installing a non-distro libtool.  (I'm running on CentOS 7.)

The lightbulb above my head lit up when I read https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html.  The search path used to find the macro files is the one defined by `--prefix`, which by default is usually `/usr/local`.  So autoconf for a package which will be installed to `/usr/local` searches `/usr/local/share/aclocal-APIVERSION` and `/usr/local/share/aclocal`.

On many distros, including CentOS7, the seven macro files for `libtools` are installed under `/usr/share/aclocal` rather than under `/usr/local/share/aclocal`.  Consequently, they aren't found when the package you are building sets prefix to `/usr/local`.

To fix this if you already have a `/usr/local/share/aclocal` directory, type the following as root:

```
for file in argz libtool ltdl ltoptions ltsugar ltversion lt~obsolete
do
  ln -s /usr/share/aclocal/$file.m4 /usr/local/share/aclocal/$file.m4
done
```

To fix this if you don't have a `/usr/local/share/aclocal` directory, type the following as root:

```
ln -s /usr/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/aclocal
```

Voilà -- problem solved.

Comment: Great tip, more or less fixed this (suuuper-aggravating, persistent) issue for me on a CentOS 7 cluster. If the project ships with an `autogen.sh` you can also modify the `exec autoreconf` line to include `-I /usr/share/alocal` along with the other options, which is what I actually did. The actual command invoked to generate the `configure` script is then `autoreconf -v -f -i -I /usr/share/aclocal`.

Answer (score 15):

you must install libtool

in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

in redhat based:

```
yum install libtool
```

Comment: The question said already this is not the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I also installed libtool and others to non-standard directories, and this error is actually autoconf not being able to find libtool's m4 macros. Yes it can be caused by libtool not being installed, but also by it being in a non-standard install directory. Here is my fix:

```
export ACLOCAL_PATH=$HOME/install/libtool/share/aclocal:$ACLOCAL_PATH
```

which I placed in my `.bash_profile`

Comment: Another way to do this: autoreconf -I $HOME/install/libtool/share/aclocal

Answer (score 1):

You need to **reinstall** it in order to fix the error so follow these steps :

1] Remove current libtool if installed: `sudo apt-get purge libtool`

2] Download it from official website https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/

3] Untar it: `tar -xzvf "name of the tar_file"`

4] Enter folder and type: `./configure && make`

5] Install it: `sudo make install`

And you are done, error should be fixed !

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> configure.ac:75 :error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
>     If this token is legitimate please use m4_pattern_allow
> ```
>
> Now, I know I have libtool installed ...

I've found this usually indicates you don't have `libtool` development gear installed (though you may have `libtool` installed).

You should install `libltdl-dev` on Debian and Ubuntu; and `libtool-ltdl-devel` on Fedora.

---

Here are the searches for the packages.

***Fedora***

```
$ yum search libtool
======================== Name Exactly Matched: libtool =========================
libtool.x86_64 : The GNU Portable Library Tool
======================= Summary & Name Matched: libtool ========================
libtool-ltdl.x86_64 : Runtime libraries for GNU Libtool Dynamic Module Loader
libtool-ltdl.i686 : Runtime libraries for GNU Libtool Dynamic Module Loader
libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64 : Tools needed for development using the GNU Libtool
                          : Dynamic Module Loader
libtool-ltdl-devel.i686 : Tools needed for development using the GNU Libtool
                        : Dynamic Module Loader
=========================== Summary Matched: libtool ===========================
mingw32-libltdl.noarch : Runtime libraries for GNU Libtool Dynamic Module Loader
mingw64-libltdl.noarch : Runtime libraries for GNU Libtool Dynamic Module Loader
```

***Ubuntu***

```
$ apt-cache search libtool
autotools-dev - Update infrastructure for config.{guess,sub} files
libltdl-dev - System independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
libltdl7 - System independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
libtool - Generic library support script
libtool-bin - Generic library support script (libtool binary)
libtool-doc - Generic library support script
...
```